# Bigquery API php authorization

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-bigquery, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to get access bigquery api using PHP library, but I always have this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/primeval-shadow-571/datasets/Test/tables: (401) Login Required' in ...

I have a web application, that needs to get some data from table in bigquery. The Remote account is not mine, but it was created by some guy (and I don't have login and pass to log in), who gave me the `.json` file which included thoose parameters:

```
auth_uri, 
client_secret, 
token_uri, 
client_email, 
client_x509_cert_url, 
client_id and 
auth_provider_x509_cert_url.
```

Here is my php code:

```
<?php

require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/Bigquery.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('google-config.json');

$service = new Google_Service_Bigquery($client);

$service->tables->listTables('primeval-shadow-571', 'Test');
```

But finally I got error that's above.

Can anybody tell me where am I wrong?

P.S. I just started work with google api two days ago, so I'm just beginning learn it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code that works for us:

```
session_start();

define('PROJECT_ID', 'edited');
define('DATASET_ID', 'edited');
define('API_KEY', 'edited');

$client_id = 'edited';
$service_account_name = 'edited';
$key_file_location = '.ssh/privatekey-bigquery.p12';
$service_token_file_location = 'bigquery_current_service_token.json';

set_include_path("google-api-php/src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once 'google-api-php/src/Google/Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php/src/Google/Service/Bigquery.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
//$client->setDeveloperKey(API_KEY);

if (!is_file($service_token_file_location)) {
    if (!is_writable($service_token_file_location)) {
        @chmod($service_token_file_location, 0777);
        if (!is_writable($service_token_file_location)) {
            die('Service token file is not writable: ' . $service_token_file_location);
        }
    }
    file_put_contents($service_token_file_location, '');
} else {
    if (!is_writable($service_token_file_location)) {
        @chmod($service_token_file_location, 0777);
        if (!is_writable($service_token_file_location)) {
            die('Service token file is not writable: ' . $service_token_file_location);
        }
    }
}
$service_token = @file_get_contents($service_token_file_location);
if (!empty($service_token)) {
    $client->setAccessToken($service_token);
}
if (!file_exists($key_file_location)) {
    die('Key file is missing: ' . $key_file_location);
}
$key = file_get_contents($key_file_location);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $service_account_name, array(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery',
        ), $key
);
$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}
$service_token = $client->getAccessToken();
file_put_contents($service_token_file_location, $service_token);

// start using $client
```